# How to clear indexeddb data in firefox?

Tags: firefox

Is there a way to clear the indexeddb data for a specific site? I'm trying to test in localhost and need to clear the data occasionally but I don't see any GUI like in chrome:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the dev tools switch to the *Storage* tab.
On the right panel, expand **Indexed DB** sub-menu and the website url you are interested in.
From there you can right click on each store and "*delete [store name]*".

[image: screenshot of the window]